# TabbarController with Default View

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an iPhone application in which there are three class Class A, Class B , Class C. Now I want to show Class A as default View with two tab for Class B and Class C using Tabbarcontroller. Can any one suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Upon launching your app, or any other time you can set what controller is shown, with the above method.

Comment: bro I want a tabbarconrtoller on Class A, I don't want to add class A in tab bar controller array.

Comment: bro, so then add the `tabBarController`'s view to your Class A's view via `addSubview:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link :  [How are the 2 View Controllers wired to the tabBarController in iPhoneRecipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029122/how-are-the-2-view-controllers-wired-to-the-tabbarcontroller-in-iphonerecipes?rq=1)

or use this:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```